# Agregar mas de un grafico en un grafico de chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

mi problema es que teniendo un grafico de line con chartjs, debo agregar mas de un label para mostrar diferentes resultados en ese grafico.

Actualmente el grafico funciona con un solo label pero el objetivo es poder tener mas labels y que el usuario pueda seleccionar cual ver.

Dejo el codigo y una imagen del grafico actual.
[image: El objetivo seria donde dice compras mensuales tambien pueda haber un compras anuales con comparacion progresiva de años anteriores]

El objetivo seria donde dice compras mensuales tambien pueda haber un compras anuales con comparacion progresiva de años anteriores

```
    const data = [10000,20000,400000,30000,5000,100000,23333,45000,6000]
    line_chart(["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"], data, 'charts', 'compras mensuales')

/*Nos movemos de archivo desde el controlador donde invoco el grafico hacia donde tengo todos los graficos que utilizo*/

    export function line_chart(labels,data, id, label){
    
    let ctx = document.getElementById(id);
    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels,
            datasets: [{
              label: label,
              lineTension: 0.3,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)",
              borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
              pointRadius: 3,
              pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
              pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
              pointHoverRadius: 3,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
              pointHitRadius: 10,
              pointBorderWidth: 2,
              data,
              FontColor  : '#FFFFF'
            }],
            
        },
        
        options: {
            
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    ticks: {
                        color:  "#FFFF"
                      }
                },
                x: {
                    ticks: {
                      color: "#FFFF"
                    }
                  }
            },
            plugins: {  
                legend: {
                  labels: {
                    color: "#FFFF",
                  }
                }
            },
            display: true, 
            responsive: true
        }
            
    });
  
}
```

Comment: El atributo datasets es un array. Para ese gráfico tienes sólo un elemento, pero nada te impide añadir un segundo elemento

Comment: si lo copio exactamente igual y lo agrego abajo, solamente me figura el ultimo añadido pero no con la opción de dos.